# Extracting lines with particular string from file

Tags: text-processing

If I copied

```
cp file.txt /home/user/file2.txt
```

And I want to take only rows with `ERROR` from the `file.txt` and put them in file `file2.txt`, how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please try to rephrase your question to make it clearer. In particular, it is unclear how the `cp` command you mention ties into the problem. Do you mean to ask "how can I select only certain lines of `file.txt` and write them to another file `file2.txt`"?

Comment: -1 please see [how to ask a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and from which source are you learning Linux that is saying `cp` can use to filter lines? or do you read the short description of the command which you are trying to learn to know what does that command do?

Comment: Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Before you execute a command, like `cp`, read the `man` page for it. E.g. `man cp`. It may keep you from asking closable questions.

Answer (score 2):

That's not what `cp` is for. `cp` is used to copy a file, not selectively grab some of its contents and put in another file.

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want. One of the simplest is:

```
grep -i ERROR file.txt > file2.txt   # Overwrite any existing file2.txt
grep -i ERROR file.txt >> file2.txt  # Append to file2.txt
```

If you only want exactly `ERROR` in all-caps, drop the `-i`.